# YAML Local Anchor?

Tags: yaml

I'm trying to simplify this data:

```
farm:
  - pets:
    - type: fish
      breedtype: fish
      name: dory
    - type: dog
      breedtype: dog
      name: lassie
```

Basically type and breedtype are always the same, unfortunately this is the case.

I've tried to simplify this by somehow using anchors

```
base: &base
  type: &type fish
  breedtype: *type
farm:
  type: &type dog
  <<: *base
```

I want the *base to inherit &type from &type dog.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach or if there's an easier way, am I looking at the problem wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't base have `breedtype: *type`?

Comment: @HawkenRives Correct, I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Given that I didn't know that YAML had the `<<` operator at all, I'm not sure I'm the right person to talk about this question, but your solution looks perfectly fine to me. Does it work?

Comment: @HawkenRives No, it unfortunately uses the &type from &base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is true that YAML defines a `<<` type, be aware that this is not part of the specification, but part of the [type repository](http://yaml.org/type/) which is based on the outdated YAML version 1.1 and has not been updated since. A YAML implementation is not required to support this type. Moreover, it does not do what you think it does, because the alias `*type` is resolved in the context where it occurs and will always link to the value `fish`.

Be aware that YAML is pure data. It is not capable of nor designed to enforce rules like *type always must match breedtype*. The schema used for loading the data is defined by the one loading it. If in your data schema, `type` always equals `breedtype`, you can just leave out `breedtype` in YAML, because when loading it into an application, you can set its value from `type`.

Comment: Unfortunately the yaml actually gets converted into another format, which I cannot manipulate, but thank you for confirming this isn't possible. I've been searching through the spec for an hour.